# Can't run my Ionic project on Android or iOS

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I need my project to run so I can test it with my phone.

When I run it with "ionic lab" it works fine except that I can't access cordova plugins (I assume that it's leggit) but when I try to "ionic cordova run android", then I get many errors that I don't understand.

It's my first Ionic & Cordova project so I'm a bit lost with all the stuff happening here. It's in Typescript.

```
Error: ./node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib'
resolve 'child_process' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\xmlhttprequest\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in vennel_ts\node_modules
        using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/child_process)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process doesn't exist
[vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.ts]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.js]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process.json]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\child_process]
 @ ./node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 15:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jsdom' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
resolve 'jsdom' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in vennel_ts\node_modules
        using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/jsdom)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom doesn't exist
[vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.ts]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.js]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom.json]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\jsdom]
 @ ./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 5:13-29
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'location' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
resolve 'location' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in vennel_ts\node_modules
        using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/location)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\location doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\location.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\location.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\location.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              vennel_ts\node_modules\location doesn't exist
[vennel_ts\node_modules\location]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\location.ts]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\location.js]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\location.json]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\location]
 @ ./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 13:24-43
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts,./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'navigator' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
resolve 'navigator' in 'vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\lib'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: vennel_ts\node_modules\jQuery\package.json (relative path: ./lib)
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in vennel_ts\node_modules
        using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: vennel_ts\package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/navigator)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator doesn't exist
            .ts
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.ts doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.json doesn't exist
            as directory
              vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator doesn't exist
[vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.ts]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.js]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator.json]
[vennel_ts\node_modules\navigator]
 @ ./node_modules/jQuery/lib/node-jquery.js 17:25-45
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/main.ts
    at new BuildError (vennel_ts\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
    at callback (vennel_ts\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\webpack.js:121:28)
    at emitRecords.err (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:269:13)
    at Compiler.emitRecords (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:375:38)
    at emitAssets.err (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:262:10)
    at applyPluginsAsyncSeries1.err (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:368:12)
    at next (vennel_ts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:218:11)
    at Compiler.compiler.plugin (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\performance\SizeLimitsPlugin.js:99:4)
    at Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries1 (vennel_ts\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:222:13)
    at Compiler.afterEmit (vennel_ts\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:365:9)
```

This is the error Visual Studio Code sends me when I try to build for Android or for iOS.